# Request header values not send? CORS - jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to make a request from one application to another. So i created some headers which are required by my application and filled them in for the Ajax Request. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://my-domain.com/apps/filters/get-filters',
    beforeSend: function(request){
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Webshop-Domain", window.location.host);
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Language", $('html').attr('lang'));
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Request-Protocol", window.location.protocol);
        request.setRequestHeader("X-Api-Version", '2');
    },
    headers: {
        "X-Webshop-Domain": window.location.host,
        "X-Language": $('html').attr('lang'),
        "X-Request-Protocol": window.location.protocol,
        "X-Api-Version": '2',
    },
    data: {}, success: function ( response )
    {

    }
});
```

Now when i load a page, this method is called but no response given. It gives me the "Header not allowed" issue. But when i check in my network tab (developer tools Chrome) i see my request, i see some headers but none of those. Does anybody has a idea how this is possible or what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of CORS (cross domain requests), only basic headers are allowed. You will need to add the headers you wish to send to the server's response header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Webshop-Domain, ...
```

Here's a related question you may find useful: [Ajax Request header field Key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26243364/ajax-request-header-field-key-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-headers)

Comment: Thanks, you helped me out a lot! :D